# Providing a resource to a property based on current data binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a few situations where I am trying to provide strongly-typed XAML markup to look up a resource for a specific object, and apply it as a binding to a property. For instance, looking up ImageSources based on the current DataContext. Or based on a new given binding.

For instance, I'd like to get markup somewhat like this to work:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter
            Property="DefaultImageSource"
            Value="{ns:ImageSourceForObject Path}" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

The ns:ImageSourceForObject would operate a lot like a Binding, ultimately resolving to a specific instance. It would then look up the ImageSource resource associated with that instance.

The main problem I am having is figuring out how to actually resolve the resource inside of ProvideValue. There seems to be no way to get a reference to a FrameworkElement.

I have the same problem inside a ValueConverter.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.providevalue.aspx):

> IProvideValueTarget reports the object reference and a property
>   identifier from the context where the markup extension is used

Thus, I would expect you to do something like this:

```
var provideValueTarget = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
var valueTarget = provideValueTarget.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;

if (valueTarget == null)
{
    // or maybe throw
    return null;
}

var resource = valueTarget.FindResource("whatever");

// etc.
```